# temperature rises when the car moves at 80km per/hour, the engine cant idle, it switches it off while idling

Tags: nissan, sunny

1. When driving at 80km per/hour, the temperature rises high.
2. the car cant idle, the engines switches itself off. by trafic light i cant stop or slow down

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Also, you have provided virtually no specific details about your situation.  What make/model/year car is this?  What is "rises high"?  What do you mean by "can't idle"?  Why can't you stop or slow down?  Is there a problem with the brakes?

Comment: you have to give some type of information about the car,what have you done to diagnose the problem what is the coolant level and how does the oil look.the more details you give the better an answer you will get.